# How can I view the return value from Future<bool>

Tags: flutter

How can I view the return value from Future

```html
 Future<bool> res;
 res = cancelDialog();
 print("res..........: ${res}");
```

my cancel dialog:

```html
Future<bool> cancelDialog(_formKey, context, cancelFn) async {
  var res = await showModalActionSheet(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      context: context,
      actions: <SheetAction>[
        SheetAction(label: "Evet", key: "evet"),
        SheetAction(label: "Hayır", key: "hayir")
      ],
      title: "Tüm değişilikler geri alınacaktır.",
      message: "Devam etmek istediğinize emin misiniz?");
  if (res == "evet") {
    _formKey.currentState?.reset();
     cancelFn.call();
     //return true;
     return Future<bool>.value(true);

  } else {
   //retun false;
    return Future<bool>.value(false);
  }
}
```

output : res..........: Instance of 'Future'

The value I want to see in the res is true or false, how can I provide it?

Thank YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to await to get the aswer of any value  for example

```
bool dialogvalue=await res;
 print(dailogvalue)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are working with a `Future<T>` object from an async API, which is actually an object that will resolve (in a future) to your `T`.

Because of that, you need to either:

```
bool result = await res;
print(result); // true or false
```

or

```
res.then((result) => print(result)); // true or false
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of `Future` you have to add await keyword before that as below:

```
 Future<bool> res;
 res = await cancelDialog();
 print("res..........: ${res}");
```

Check it out and do let me know if you face the problem.

Comment: This contains an obvious type error. await keyword resolves the Future to the its completion type